# Issue with creating oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having problem coming up with following query.

```
id| prop_id| obj_id| value|
1         7       2      1
2         8       2      1
4         7       5      7 
5         8       5      12
```

**Input parameters** to the query are:

- Collection of (prop_id, value) pairs

We must select records whose `prop_id` and `values` match input parameters: but there is also one constrain, the `obj_id` of resulting records must be same. If it is not same, result must be empty. Otherwise it must return `obj_id`.

**Example**:

Let's say input parameters are: (7,1) and (8,12).

Now there are two records with such values: first and last.
However, `obj_id` of first record is 2 and `obj_id` of second record is 5. Hence, the result must be empty because 2!=5.

Another example:

Let's say input parameters are: (7,7) and (8,12).

Now there are two records with such values: **last two records.**
`obj_id` of first is 5 and `obj_id` of second record is also 5. Hence, the result must be 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
select obj_id from table 
where (prop_id=7 and value=7) or (prop_id=8 and value=12)
group by obj_id having count(*)=2 and count(distinct object_id)=1
```

Comment: Thank but I am having problem. This is the output I get after this query: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: This was my query: "select OBJECT_ID from  COMP_INFO.OBJECT_VALUES
where (PROPERTY_ID,VALUE_INT) in (7,7) or (PROPERTY_ID,VALUE_INT) in (8,12)
group by OBJECT_ID having count(*)=2 and count(distinct OBJECT_ID)=1"